# Grunt - modify JS file while building

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, production

I am using Grunt as my task manager and would like to change JS file/s while building bundle for production. My main goal is to change config files and data inside them because data is different. What is the best possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a replace module of grunt:
[grunt-text-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace) or [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace)

And I recommend that you insert a key on your file to replace via grunt in all environments.

Answer (score 1):

The grunt text-replace package https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace is what you are looking for I think.